# I got the following error after adding images in my flutter project :-

Tags: flutter, pubspec.yaml

Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 62, column 4: Expected a key while parsing a block mapping.
╷
62 │    assets:
│    ^
╵
Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Exception: Please correct the pubspec.yaml file at .\pubspec.yaml
Restarted application in 204ms.

[image]
I uncommented the assets section in the pubspec.yaml file and I also added the correct path of the file like this :-

## To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:

assets:
- assets/images/

But I can not see the image in the app and got the above error.

Comment: yaml is using a specific indenting. You need to put the - assets/images/ on the next line

Comment: I is in the next lie only.

Comment: Can you make sure that line 62 starts from 1 tab of space (or 2 spacebars of space) and line 63 starts with 2 tabs of space (or 4 spacebars of space).

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your pubspec.yaml?

Comment: I can not post screenshot because I don't have enough badges to upload images.

Comment: The problem kind of got resolved after I added the file name to the path. Thanks to all for the suggestions.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/1772220)